# BI/ Reporting Tool

Tags: civireport, reports, custom-reports

Any recommendations on a Business Intelligence/ Reporting Tool? I have used Crystal Reports, IBM Cognos and Oracle Answers in my working life. I am now retired and helping a small community organization with their CiviCRM. I have heard about Reportico, Jasper etc. What do you folks use mostly - and pros and cons? Muchas Gracias in advance.

Comment: I have used Apache Zeppelin as a data visualization tool before. The good thing I loves was that it was easy to get it up and running and easy to create graphs based on an SQL statement. 
I have also some experience with Pentaho but that one I found more complex to use.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how well you know sql and civicrm schema and what kind of report you want

I've used a mix of metabase (awesome to explore with their query builder, and fairly powerful with the option to write your own query) and civisualize (more powerful, but you need to write your queries in sql and the viz in javascript)

I'd recommend installing metabase and see how far you can go with it

Comment: Thanks. I am maybe a 3 out of 5 as far as sql proficiency is concerned. I can extract whatever data I need. I was talking of a BI/ Reporting tool more for the need to produce formatted reports and graphical outputs. I will take a lok at metabase.